# A simple scatterplot example in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, d3.js

I'm looking for an example of how to draw a scatterplot in D3.js.

I haven't been able to find a simple example by looking through the [official D3.js examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) (impressive though they are). I just want to know how to:

- draw and label the x- and y-axes
- draw scatter points on the graph.

I did find [this example](http://novus.github.com/nvd3/examples/scatterWithLegend.html) in this [D3 reusable library](https://github.com/novus/nvd3), but it is much more complex than I need, with external files that make it hard to pull out the essential points. Could anyone point me at a simple scatterplot example to get started?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I never used d3 before and gave up trying to put together a working example. It seems you need to transform the data and the axes to make something conventional (the default y axis points down). Here are the pages I used: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-scatterplot/ and http://bl.ocks.org/1166403 Hope they help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should get you started.  You can see it in action at http://bl.ocks.org/2595950.

```
// data that you want to plot, I've used separate arrays for x and y values
var xdata = [5, 10, 15, 20],
    ydata = [3, 17, 4, 6];

// size and margins for the chart
var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60}
  , width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// x and y scales, I've used linear here but there are other options
// the scales translate data values to pixel values for you
var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(xdata)])  // the range of the values to plot
          .range([ 0, width ]);        // the pixel range of the x-axis

var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(ydata)])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);

// the chart object, includes all margins
var chart = d3.select('body')
.append('svg:svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr('class', 'chart')

// the main object where the chart and axis will be drawn
var main = chart.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('class', 'main')   

// draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient('left');

main.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
.attr('class', 'main axis date')
.call(yAxis);

// draw the graph object
var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(ydata)  // using the values in the ydata array
  .enter().append("svg:circle")  // create a new circle for each value
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d); } ) // translate y value to a pixel
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(xdata[i]); } ) // translate x value
      .attr("r", 10) // radius of circle
      .style("opacity", 0.6); // opacity of circle
```

Used like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The d3 test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='content'>
      <!-- /the chart goes here -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scatterchart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really working for me - not sure where `flipy` comes from?

Comment: Sorry about that, I assumed that his example was working. I've updated my answer and simplified things a bit to hopefully make things more clear. You can see it working at http://bl.ocks.org/2595950.

Comment: This will sound ridiculous... but I'm so new that even seeing the above doesn't let me know what to do. I copy the scatterplot.js code where "The chart goes here" is in the .html? I leave the html alone and create a scatterplot.js file with the above in the same directory? For whatever reason all the tutorials I see just show the .js code. I've got no experience with javascript and don't even know what to do with it. Is there a full html file example that 'just works' so I can study it? Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the html part into a file called `index.html` and copy the javascript into a file called `scatterchart.js` and put them in the same directory.  Open up `index.html` in a browser (IE9+, FF, Chrome) and it should just work.  You can see  http://bl.ocks.org/2595950 to get an idea of what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

NVD3.js has great examples. You will need to include their library also or take a look at their implementation. Take a look at this example of scatterplot: http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example of scatterplot with C3.js (D3-based): http://c3js.org/samples/chart_scatter.html

You can chang radius size like this : http://grokbase.com/t/gg/c3js/14a7jfj28c/bubble-chart-with-changing-radius-size-in-c3-js